# In which locations can I mine the most iron ore?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there an area that has a lot of iron ore? I'm working on building up my armorsmith level and iron is the next step.

Comment: Have you tried googling at all...? There are several sites like this one: http://pwniversity.com/gw2/farming/iron-ore

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter You should turn that into an answer and include the images for the most profitable of the routes shown.

Comment: @Brian: I considered that, but, without wanting to sound elitist, I think it's reasonable to expect the OP to do at least a minimal amount of research. If you can google and find the answer to your question within a minute, should it really be a question on an SE site?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Yes it absolutely should. Users should come to Arqade to find answers on gaming questions. Keeping a great collection of questions and answers is key to the site.

Comment: @DavidYell: I agree to some extent, but the line has to be drawn at some level of triviality, wouldn't you say? I don't see the value of answering with a link (which may not be up anymore in a year or two), and I don't want to invest time in writing a more thorough answer. Note I didn't down-vote the question, but I'm not going to answer it either if it's just a matter of googling (or in the case of GW2, looking it up on the wiki). Hence my comment - I'm sure you've noticed the lack of upvotes on the question, so I think I'm not alone with my opinion, but feel free to answer if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The best place by far is in Brisband wildlands at Gallowfields Waypoint, here is the wp link to it [&BGMAAAA=]

First of all, there is a rich iron node just by the wp, and a lot more nodes are scattered in the area. You can easily get 20-30 iron ores from one run around a small area.

Just beware to jump down the right place, as the rich ore is down in a cliff, and falling all the way down will kill you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would go to the Iron Marches. The maps in Ascalon that are Charr based have a lot of iron.

If you go to this site gw2timer.com/?page=Map&section=Resource and select iron and "show possible nodes" you will get a good map of where to start. This map is zoomable.

Guild Gathering Bonus will give you %15 bonus chance to harvest more, so will Guild Hero Banners.

Comment: If you go to this site http://gw2timer.com/?page=Map&section=Resource and select iron and "show possible nodes" you will get a good map of where to start. This map is zoomable.